# nrf24L01 with/without antenna

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

the function write in nrf24LO1 (without antenna) works perfectly
but in nrf24LO1 (with antenna) not works. why?!
the code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <printf.h>

 RF24 radio(7,8);
 const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_HIGH);
  radio.setCRCLength(RF24_CRC_8); 
  radio.stopListening();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  const char text[] = "example";
  if(radio.write(&text,sizeof(text))) //<==problem here
    Serial.println("ok");
  Serial.println(text);
  delay(1000);
}
```

nrf24l01 with antenna :
[image]

nrf24l01 without antenna :
[image]

Comment: In what way does it "not works"?

Comment: not works : Not send data , function write return false with 0 data sending to recever

Comment: what makes you believe that the two modules are interchangeable? .. btw, both of the modules have an antenna

Comment: They actually are interchangeable. But your program has an error `radio.write` expects a pointer to some data. An array and a pointer are pretty much the same in C (this is a bit oversimplified but sufficient in this case). But you are passing a pointer to an array (the address of the array), which in turn would be a pointer to a pointer to data. Your program may or may not work just because of pure luck and the current flow of aether. Remove the apmersand in that method call.

Comment: Are you communicating between identical modules? How far apart are the modules?

Comment: Try increasing the distance between the two. Or use `RF24_PA_LOW` during testing.